# jQuery doesn't load when i parse html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a PHP/Mysql file with a table generated from rows with Popover inside.
Location ex: `/lib/datatable.php`

I'm doing a jQuery Call from another file ex: `/lib/GetTable.php` 
here: `/lib/GetTable.php`  (in head scripts and `css` are loaded fine)

```
function getTable() {
  $.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url: 'datatable.php',
     async: 'false',
     data:{ status: 'doIt'},
     success: function(response) {
         $("#getTable").html(response).fadeIn(500);
     }});
}
getTable();
```

Datatable.php

```
<?php    
$res = $db->query("SELECT * FROM datatable");
        while ($res = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
 <tr>
<td class="font-small-2">?=$result['name'];?></td>
<td class="font-small-2">?=$result['number'];?></td>
<td class="font-small-2"><?=$result['data'];?></td>
<td class="font-small-2"><span data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-container="body" data-original-title="Reason" data-html="true" data-content="?=$result['reasonfull'];?>"><?=substr($result['reasonfull'],0,40;?>..</span></td>
</tr>

    <?php } ?>
```

When result is loaded, popover doesn't work. 
I've tested Modal & Tooltip but nothing. In Browser console there is no error.

Is there any solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: the question is unclear . do take your time to explain the problem briefly and what is the  roor you are getting .? try checking in console. if is it in ajax call check in the network tab in browser;s developer tools can checks the status code in the responses

Comment: if you are expecting a html response in response for the ajax call then add `dataType : 'html',` in your ajax call .

Comment: @AnikethSaha i'm removing this post, to post another with more details! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: edit this question . No need to delete it

Comment: @AnikethSaha done , hope this time is more clear... Changed the example to a bootstrap table with popover inside

Comment: show your datatable.php and also  add `dataType : 'html'` and `console.log(response)`

Comment: Is the AJAX response replacing the elements that have popovers on them? Widgets don't automatically re-attach to elements that are added dynamically.

Comment: You need to reinitialize the `Popover` widget in the `success:` function.

Comment: @AnikethSaha updated with datatable.php , tested with dataType didn't work either..

Comment: where is is `getTable` in html?

Comment: @George didn't posted entire HTML cuz it is a disaster but is there id="getTable" :)

Comment: you mean tooltip popup not working?

Comment: It should be `$res['name']`olinstead of `$result['name']` and where is the echo for the getting as a response in ajax response!